How to numerically integrate the following expression?
Let
fK[T_, D_, t_, H_] := 
 Integrate[(r - t)^(H - 1/2), {r, T, T + D}]

fI[T_, D_, s_, u_, H_] := 
 Integrate[((r - u) (r - s))^(H - 1/2), {r, T, T + D}]

.
I would like to obtain a numeric solution to
TT = 1/365.25; DD = 30/365.25; H = 0.1;

Integrate[
 Integrate[
  fK[TT, DD, u, H] fI[TT, DD, s, u, H], {u, s, TT}], {s, 
  0, TT}]

.
Unfortunately the expression that Mathematica returns is very implicit and when I use NIntegrate, it seems to have an issue with the inner integral extremum s.

Semi-numeric
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"]

$Version 
(*"14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

TT = Rationalize[1/365.25, 0];
DD = Rationalize[30/365.25, 0]; 
H = Rationalize[0.1, 0];

fK[T_, d_, t_, H_] := Integrate[(r - t)^(H - 1/2), {r, T, T + d}];
fI[T_, d_, s_, u_, H_] := Integrate[((r - u)  (r - s))^(H - 1/2), {r, T, T + d}];

FF = fK[TT, DD, u, H]*fI[TT, DD, s, u, H]
(*A nice output*)

NIntegrate[FF[[1]], {s, 0, TT}, {u, s, TT}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(*2.3019865399534017781*10^-6*)

All numeric computing:
 ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"]

 TT = Rationalize[1/365.25, 0]; 
 DD = Rationalize[30/365.25, 0]; 
 H = Rationalize[0.1, 0]; 

 fK[T_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, H_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(r - t)^(H - 1/2), {r, T, T + d}];
 fI[T_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ, H_? NumericQ] := NIntegrate[((r - u)  (r - s))^(H - 1/2), {r, T, T + d}];
 FF[s_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ] = fK[TT, DD, u, H]*fI[TT, DD, s, u, H];
 NIntegrate[FF[s, u], {s, 0, TT}, {u, s, TT}]
 (*2.30199*10^-6*)


What does FF[[1]] mean?

@MrFrog . It's mean first part of expression. You have conditions from Integrate, but I need only  a solution.
